# JRuby Oracle connection failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am following a tutorial to establish ojdbc connection in JRuby so that I can execute some SQL statements. But it is failing to connect to the database. Below are the steps:

1. Copied ojdbc6.jar under working directory where the ruby files reside.
2. Created oracle_connection.rb file
3. Create test_connection.rb file as the driver class

oracle_connection.rb

```
require 'java'
require 'ojdbc6.jar'
java_import 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

 java_import 'java.sql.DriverManager'

class OracleConnection
@conn = nil
@user = nil
@pwd = nil

def initialize(user, pwd, url)
    @user = user
    @pwd = pwd
    @url = url


    #Load driver class
    ora_driver = OracleDriver.new

    DriverManager.registerDriver ora_driver
    @conn = DriverManager.get_connection url, user, pwd
    @conn.auto_commit = false
end

#Add getters and setters for all attributes we wish to expose
attr_reader :user, :pwd, :url, :connection

def close_connection()
    @conn.close() unless @conn
end

def prepare_call(call)
    @conn.prepare_call call
end

def create_statement()
    @conn.create_statement
end

def prepare_statement(sql)
    @conn.prepare_statement sql
end

def commit()
    @conn.commit
end

def to_s
    "OracleConnection [user=#{@user}, url=#{@url}]"
end
alias_method :to_string, :to_s
end


#test_connection.rb
require 'oracle_connection'

#Edit these for your database schema
user = "ABC"
pwd = "EFG"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:1520/db_instance"

print "Run at #{Time.now} using JRuby #{RUBY_VERSION}\n\n"

begin
   conn = OracleConnection.new.create(user, pwd, url)

   puts conn, "\n"
end

print "\nEnded at #{Time.now}\n"
```

While running test_connection.rb, I see the below error:

```
ruby test_connection.rb
Run at 2013-09-16 10:11:05 -0700 using JRuby 1.9.2
NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for OracleConnection:Class
(root) at test_connection.rb:11
```

I don't know what is causing the problem. Guidance on this is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In "test_connection.rb" I was calling "create" method whereas in OracleConnection class "create" method is not defined. Hence it was failing.

Replacing  *conn = OracleConnection.new.create(user, pwd, url)* with  *conn = OracleConnection.new(user, pwd, url)* fixes the issue.

Below I am re-writing the working test_connection.rb

```
#test_connection.rb
require 'oracle_connection'

#Edit these for your database schema
user = "ABC"
pwd = "EFG"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:1520/db_instance"

print "Run at #{Time.now} using JRuby #{RUBY_VERSION}\n\n"

begin
   conn = OracleConnection.new(user, pwd, url)

   puts conn, "\n"
end

print "\nEnded at #{Time.now}\n"
```